# Is it possible to have a common accessible file location for the sandboxed main app and its plugin extension app

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox, mac-app-store

I am trying to launch an app to mac app store. The main app bundle and everything inside it is sandboxed.

The Bundle Identifier of the main app is `com.xxx.core.app`.
The Bundle Identifier of the inner Plugin Finder Extension app is `com.xxx.core.app.extensions`.

Now the problem is the inner finder extension is also sandboxed and it is trying to read a file written by the main app.

The main app writes the file to the following temp location of mac OS X i.e.
`/var/folder/jv11743453495593/T/com.xxx.core.app`

But the inner Plugins try to read it from `/var/folder/jv11743453495593/T/com.xxx.core.app/extensions`

Due to different bundle identifiers they have different containers.

Can anyone let me know how to restrict the same app and its plugins to the same folder location. Is there any work around for this problem.